# Spring Boot JMS - Generic JSON messages without _type property

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-jms, converters

I'm implementing JMS in a Spring Boot application.  Everything is going well.  However I'm very surprised at the tight coupling between JSON messages and Java objects.  I am looking for some direction on a more flexible solution.

Going through examples and using the MappingJackson2MessageConverter, everything is great as long as you are sending and receiving in the same application.  Under the covers it's extremely tightly coupled to the java object.  If I have a simple java object called person:

```
package acme.receivingapp.dto;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
...
}
```

When the JmsTemplate turns that into a message the JSON looks generic enough:

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}
```

However it includes this property:

```
"_type" : "acme.superapp.dto.Person"
```

If the JmsListener isn't using that exact Java class, it throws an exception.  That's true even if the class is functionally the same as in this example where it's effectively the same class but just in a different package:

```
package wonderco.sendingapp.dto;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
...
}
```

We will be receiving messages from many external entities from mainframes, python apps, .Net, etc.  I cannot require them to include our object types in a _type property.

I could create my own MessageConverter specifically for a Person object, but if we have hundreds of more messages / java classes it would be unwieldy to have so many message converters.  I would need to design something more generic that can work for any type of JSON message /  java class.

Before I go down the path of designing my own generic solution is there anything more generic that works like Spring RestControllers and Spring RestTemplates in the sense that the JSON messages aren't so tightly coupled to the very specific Java classes?  I feel like I can't possibly be the first person trying to crack this nut.

Comment: There needs to be a mechanism to determine what is being received as a single queue could hold different messages with different types. If you receive multiple types of messages it needs to know what to do. How should it know what type to use? If you have 5 `@JmsListener` for the same queue with different types, it cannot use thet ype information on the listener. The generic solution you are talking about is already there in spring, using the type. You could extend it a little and use a type mapping (like sending `person` as a type and map that to a certain class on the receiving side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've got a handle on this.  I'll try to explain it to hopefully help the next person who is new to Spring / JMS.

As M.Deinum points out, unlike a REST endpoint, a queue could potentially contain many different types of messages.  Even if your implementation will only have one type of message per queue. Because queues allow any number of different messages that was the design for the provided `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`.  Because the assumption was made there will always be multiple types of messages, there must be a mechanism to determine how to unmarshal the JSON for different types of messages into the correct type of Java Object.

All the examples you'll find of using a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` will have this setup in them:

```java
MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
 
converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
```

That's telling the message converter to set the object type in a property called `_type` when creating a message or to read the object type from that property when reading a message.   There's no magic in that `_type` property.  It's not a standard.  It's just what the Spring folks used in their examples and then a bazillion people cut and pasted it.  So for your own messages, you can change that to a more appropriate property name if you like.  So in my example, I might call the property `acme_receivingapp_message_type` if I wanted.  I would then tell the external entities sending me messages to include that property with the message type.

By default, the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` will write the object type into whatever property name you chose (_type or whatever) as the fully qualified class name. In my example, it's `acme.receivingapp.dto.Person`.  When a message is received, it looks at the type property to determine what type of Java object to create from the JSON.

Pretty straightforward so far, but still not very convenient if the people sending me messages are not using Java.  Even if I can convince everyone to send me `acme.receivingapp.dto.Person`, what happens if I refactor that class from Person to Human? Or even just restructure the packages? Now I've got to go back and tell the 1,000 external entities to stop sending the property as `acme.receivingapp.dto.Person` and now send it as `acme.receivingapp.dto.Human`?

Like I stated in my original question, the message and Java class are being very tightly coupled together which doesn't work when you are dealing with external systems/entities.

The answer to my problem is right in the name of the `**Mapping**Jackson2MessageConverter` message converter.  The key there is the "mapping". Mapping refers to mapping message types to Java classes which is what we want. It's just that, by default, because no mapping information is provided, the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` simply uses the fully qualified java class names for creating and receiving messages. All we need to do is provide the mapping information to the message converter so it can map from friendly message-types (e.g.. "Person") to specific classes within our application (e.g. acme.receivingapp.dto.Person).

If you wanted your external systems/entities that will be sending you messages to simply include the property `acme_receivingapp_message_type : Person` and you wanted that unmarshalled to an `acme.receivingapp.dto.Person` object when it's received on your end, you'd setup your message converter like this:

```java
@Bean
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("acme_receivingapp_message_type");

    // Set up a map to convert our friendly message types to Java classes.
    Map<String, Class<?>> typeIdMap = new HashMap<>();
    typeIdMap.put("Person", acme.receivingapp.dto.Person.class);
    converter.setTypeIdMappings(typeIdMap);

    return converter;
}
```

That solves the problem of tight coupling between the message type property and Java class names.  But what if you'll only be dealing with a single message type in your queue and don't want the people sending messages to have to include any property to indicate the message type? Well `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` simply doesn't support that.  I tried using a "null" key in the map and then leaving the property off the message and unfortunately it doesn't work.  I wish it did support that "null" mapping to use when the property wasn't present.

If you have the scenario where your queue will only deal with one type of message and you don't want the sender to have to include a special property to indicate the message type, you'll likely want to write your own message converter.  That convertor will blindly unmarshal the JSON to the one java class you'll always be dealing with.  Or maybe you opt to just receive it as a `TextMessage` and unmarshal it in your listener.

Hopefully this helps someone because I found it quite confusing initially.

Comment: Ah yes. I totally forgot that you can configure the message converter to do this for you actually. Also how is **just receive it as a Text message and unmarshal it in your listener** different then writing your own `MessageConverter`? It does the same but instead of using Spring you are now doing it yourself (but that might be me). Glad my comment pointed you to the direction.

Comment: As to why I mentioned writing your own message convertor or just having your listener unmarshal the JSON to an object in the case of a queue designed to only deal with one type of message....   I hadn't gone through the exercise of doing it yet.  So I was just thinking out-loud and enumerating all the ways I could think of to approach the problem.   I wasn't suggesting unmarshalling in your listener is the best approach.  My assumption is writing your own message converter is the best approach.  But since I handn't personally done it yet, I didn't want to state that categorically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reacting to this thread because I have exactly the same feeling!

Why spring isn't able to deserialise the event based on the prototype function that implement the `@JmsListener` ?

If you have a function like

```
@JmsListener(destination = "#{beanQueue.queueName}")
public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

Why do we need to explicitly define the `_type` property that allow to know the java type output? We can extract it from the parameter function.

I don't perform deep search under the hood, but it look reasonable to me

---

[EDIT] After some debugging and some quick research, I found a solution. I'm not convinced that it's the more elegant solution, but at least it allow to have a kind of generic converter.

#### Convert all to String

Convert automatically all event to the `java.lang.String` type, in order to have a generic `_type` for all consumer

It can be done by encapsulate the actual `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`

```
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Setup the object mapper

        final MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        messageConverter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        messageConverter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");

        return new MessageConverter() {
            @Override
            public Message toMessage(Object object, Session session) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
                try {
                    final String stringValue = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
                    return messageConverter.toMessage(stringValue, session);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws JMSException, MessageConversionException {
                return messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
            }
        };
    }
```

#### Read all from String

In order to read all from String without need to rewrite all the actual spring implementation, we can take benefit of the `ConversionService`

```
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter((Converter<String, MyEvent>) source -> {
            try {
                return new ObjectMapper().readValue(source, MyEvent.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

#### Limitation

There is some limitation, since the event is now transfered as a String, which is not elegant at all..

I don't actually investigate with the `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType` that allow to define other type of message.

In addition, it force the client to always define a converter for all event that are listening inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimenting today and found that it's possible to create a `spring-messaging` converter instead of `spring-jms` converter to do this.

---

First, create a `org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

public class AutoJackson2MessageConverter implements MessageConverter {
    // members ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    // constructor(s) ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public AutoJackson2MessageConverter() {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    // methods ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(final Message<?> message, final Class<?> targetClass) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(message.getPayload().toString(), targetClass);
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new MessageConversionException(message, null, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> toMessage(final Object payload, final MessageHeaders headers) {
        try {
            return (
                MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload (objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload))
                    .copyHeaders (headers)
                .build()
            );
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new MessageConversionException(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, configure the `MessageHandlerMethodFactory` that `spring-jms` uses with that converter:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
                           https://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">

    <!-- JMS Configuration ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.brokerURL}"/>
        <property name="userName"  value="${activemq.credentials.username}"/>
        <property name="password"  value="${activemq.credentials.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageHandlerMethodFactory"
          class="org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory">
        <property name="messageConverter">
            <bean class="com.example.messaging.AutoJackson2MessageConverter"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jms:annotation-driven handler-method-factory="messageHandlerMethodFactory"/>

    <jms:listener-container factory-id="jmsListenerContainerFactory"
                            connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"/>


</beans>
```

And an example JMS listener like this works when processing text messages:

```java
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.JmsResponse;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

@JmsListener(destination = "${endpoints.example.getFoo}")
public JmsResponse<Message<ExampleGetFooResponse>> getFoo(final Message<ExampleGetFooRequest> request) {
    // Process the request and return the response.
}
```

---

*Disclaimer: I haven't done enough testing to consider this a production-ready solution, but it works as a proof-of-concept.*